# Need help to solve ODE $y'(x) = -\tanh(y(x))$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve the ODE

$$y'(x) = -\tanh(y(x))$$

It is separable, so diving by $\tanh(y(x))$ and integrating wrt $x$ we get $$\int \frac{y'(x)}{\tanh(y(x))} \,dx = \int -1\,dx$$

I am having trouble finding the first integral. How do I proceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Separate $y'(x) = -\tanh(y(x))$ as

$$\frac{dy}{\tanh y} =-dx$$

Then, integrate both sides

$$\ln (\sinh y )=-x+C$$

Comment: Does this also work for complex functions? In that case it seems like we run into trouble if we wish to invert sinh(y)

Comment: @StannisBa - In general, yes. There are corresponding complex inverse functions

Comment: So if I take $arcsinh(w)$ to be $\ln(\sqrt{w^2 +1} +w)$ and choosing the principal branch of the logarithm I would be able to find the solution $w$ without issues?

Answer (score 2):

$$\int \coth y dy =-x+c \implies \ln \sinh y=(-x+c)$$ $$\implies y=\sinh^{-1}e^{c-x}.$$

Comment: You should have $\ln|\sinh y|$.

Comment: @Bernard: That's totally false. Nobody said the integral was a real integral.

Answer (score 1):

Start with:$$\int \frac{dy}{\tanh(y)} = \int\frac{\cosh(y)}{\sinh(y)}\,dy.$$  Let $u = \sinh(y), du = \cosh(y)\,dy$.  This gives us $$\int\frac{\cosh(y)}{\sinh(y)}\,dy = \int \frac{du}{u} = \ln|u| + C$$ and so $$\int \frac{dy}{\tanh(y)}  = \ln|\sinh(y)| + C.$$